# How can I write ansible condition when not changed?

Tags: module, ansible, conditional-statements, .when

I'm trying to write a `when` condition when registered value changed, failed, skipped and ok (desired state) cases but I can write for all 3 scenario other than ok

```yaml
tasks
  - name: task 1
    module:
    register: result
  - name: task 2
    module
    when: result is failed
  - name: task 3
    module
    when: result is succeeded
  - name: task 4
    module
    when: result is skipped
```

I need help to write when condition if the task 1 status is "ok". Kindly suggest

Comment: Write your playbook and a debug tasks with the var `result`

Comment: => `result is succeeded and result is not changed` and if you have ansible > 2.1 and are a grammar freak => `result is success and result is not change`